# Benefits to recompiling source using newer IDE

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, mfc

I have a shared DLL that was last compiled in 1997 using Visual Studio 6. We're now using this application and shared DLL on MS Server 2008 and it seems less stable.

I'm assuming if I recompiled using VS 2005 or newer, it would also include improvements in the included Microsoft libraries, right? Is this common to have to recompile for MS bug fixes?

Is there a general practice when it comes to using old compiled code in newer environments?

edit:

[image]

Comment: If you actually _can_ recompile this ancient code, go for it! Compilers became a lot more standard-conforming and now are way more restrictive with respect to non-standard code. Prepare for a refactoring session. By the way: It's not about the IDE, but the underlying compiler.

Comment: @stefan I did get it to recompile. It wasn't complex.

Comment: You're lucky. Just do it ;-) (And don't forget to test, but that should be done with any code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really speak from a MS/VS-specific vantage point, but my experiences with other compilers have been the following:

1. The ABI (i.e. calling conventions or layout of class information) may change between compilers or even compiler versions. So you may get weird crashes if you compile the app and the library with different compiler versions. (That's why there are things like COM or NSObject -- they define a stable way for different modules to talk to each other)
2. Some OSes change their behaviour depending on the compiler version that generated a binary, or the system libraries it was linked against. That way they can fix bugs without breaking workarounds. If you use a newer compiler or build again with the newer libraries, it is assumed that you test again, so they expect you to notice your workaround is no longer needed and remove it. (This usually applies to the entire application, though, so an older library in a newer app generally gets the new behavior, and its workarounds have *already* broken.
3. The new compiler may be better. It may have a better optimizer and generate faster code, it may have bugs fixed, it may support new CPUs.
4. A new compiler/new libraries may have newer versions of templates and other stub, glue and library code that gets compiled into your application (e.g. C++ template classes). This may be a variant of #3, or of #1 above. E.g. if you have an older implementation of a std::vector that you pass to the newer app, it might crash trying to use parts of it that have changed. Or it might just be less efficient or have less features.

So in general it's a good idea to use a new compiler, but it also means you should be careful and test it thoroughly to make sure you don't miss any changes.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged this with "C++" and "MFC". If you actually have a C++ interface, you *really* should compile the DLL with the same compiler that you build the clients with. MS doesn't keep the C++ ABI completely stable across compiler versions (especially the standard library), so incompatibilities could lead to subtle errors.

In addition, newer compilers are generally better at optimizing.

Comment: That's an interesting comment. I think the main process that uses THIS DLL has been edited/compiled more recently.

Answer (score 0):

If the old dll seems more stable, in my experience, it's only because bugs are obscured better with VC6. (Use of extensive runtime checks with the new version?!)

The main benefit is, that you can debug the dll seamlessly while interacting with the main application. There are other improvements you won't want to miss, e.g. CTime being able to hold dates past year 2037.